# [PHP][Laravel] Cant download file / response download in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, download

im trying to download file using Laravel download response. The problem is probably the route is missing or went wrong, and it shows 404 Error Not Found. I'm using symlink on my storage file so it can be seen in public and it stores my files also.

[image]

[image]

Blade :

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <label for="lampiran" class="form-label">Lampiran</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control @error('lampiran') is-invalid @enderror"
          value="{{ $dokumentasi->lampiran }}" readonly>
          {{-- <span class="input-group-text"><a href="{{ route('history.download', Crypt::encrypt($dokumentasi->id)) }}"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span> --}}
          <span class="input-group-text"><a href="{{ route('history.download', ($dokumentasi->lampiran)) }}"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public function download($file_name)
{
    $file_path = base_path($file_name);

    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

Route / web.php :

```
Route::get('/lampiran-nde/{file}', 'download')->name('history.download');
```

Comment: You want to use public_path or storage_path function, depending on your needs, not base_path function. base_path points to the root of your project, so when using it you will have to prepend required path like storage/

Comment: You show `Route::get('/lampiran-nde/{file}', 'download')->name('history.download');` but the picture you show, shows a different url. Can you verify this is the correct route?

Comment: And as a tip: You can remove the 404 image and just state you got a 404. The image is overkill :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, yes i can verify i'm using the syntax above to use my route, i'm thinking that '/lampiran-nde' should be removed or not ?

Comment: @Lk77 If i use the public_path, will the code be like this ? $file_path = public_path('/storage/lampiran-nde' .$file_name);

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabe yes but note that you can redirect to the file in the public directory instead of downloading it